# js код iframe +неограниченок колличество ссылок +время перехода для каждои ссылки + прокрутка ссылки определенное количество раз

Tags: javascript

```
< iframe id="rotate_sites" src="" width="600" height="850" frameborder="1">
</iframe>
< script>
var websites = 1,
    sites =['http://mpets.mobi','http://mpets.mobi'];
function newSite() {
    if ( websites >= sites.length ) {
        websites = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById('rotate_sites').src = sites[websites];
    websites++;    
}
setInterval(newSite, 2000);
< /script>
```

Вот у меня есть такой код, я хочу чтоб вы мне немного помогли:

1. Чтобы для каждой ссылки была свое время, через которое будет загружена другая страница.
2. Количество повторов определенной ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var websites = 0,
  site1 = {
    siteName: 'http://ya.ru',
    siteTime: 1000
  },
  site2 = {
    siteName: 'http://google.com',
    siteTime: 2000
  },
  site3 = {
    siteName: 'http://ru.stackoverflow.com',
    siteTime: 3000
  },
  sites = [site1, site2, site3];

  function newSite() {
    var size = sites.length - 1;
    console.log(sites[websites].siteName)

    if ( websites >= size ) {
      websites = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById('rotate_sites').src = sites[websites].siteName;

    setTimeout(newSite, sites[websites].siteTime)
    websites++;
  }

  newSite();
```

```html
<iframe id="rotate_sites" src="" width="800" height="600" frameborder="1"></iframe>
```